# Crop image in Java with a class?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, symbols, drawimage

I have been attempting to do this for about a week. Every single time I have tried something it failed. So I turned to copying others code... they said the code worked for them... yet it failed for me.

The piece of code that I ended up liking came from the following.

[How To Crop Image in Java (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386064/how-to-crop-to-the-image-in-java)

So then from that I basically copied / made this.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageEditor {

    public BufferedImage crop(BufferedImage src, Rectangle rect) {
        BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = dest.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(src, 0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight(), rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getX() + rect.getWidth(), rect.getY() + rect.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        return dest;
    }
}
```

I got the following errors with this code.

[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 1]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error says it can't find method `drawImage(BufferedImage,int,int,double,double,double,double,double,double,<nulltype>)`.  All those double values are coming from a Rectangle, right?

[Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) has a `drawImage(BufferedImage,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,ImageObserver)` method.  That's probably the one you are trying to use.  You should use int values instead.

The second error says it can't find constructor `BufferedImage(double, double, int)`.  This is a similar problem.

Rectangle exposes int precision fields `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width`.  Can you use them?  E.g., `rect.x` instead of `rect.getX()`