# Crop image's area with openCV (java)

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, crop

I have detected a area (rectangle) in my image with openCv and i have stored the 4 points of rectangle with their coordinates.

I would to crop the original image in this area.

I have:

```
Mat image_original; 
Point p1,p2,p3,p4;
Mat image_output;
```

How i do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963464/opencv-crop-image-using-four-points/43632434#43632434

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Mat image_original; 
Point p1,p2,p3,p4;
Rect rectCrop = new Rect(p1.x, p1.y , (p4.x-p1.x+1), (p4.y-p1.y+1));
Mat image_output= image_original.submat(rectCrop);
```

This is the code for croping image as per your requirement.I assumed that `Point p1` is the top-left corner of the crop rectangle and `Point p4` is the bottom-right corner of the crop rectangle as you have not mentioned anything about their positions.

Comment: Another question: if i want crop the image near a contours (it is a List<MatOfPoint>)  instead of a precise rectangle with 4 point, it is possibile?

Comment: @doctorWW Please accept / upvote if this answer your question. Different question should be _new_ questions. Hint: get the boundingRect of your contours points, and then use `submat`