# SetClip(Java Swing) based on Constraint

Tags: java, swing

How to set constraint On the Image so that Image should not spills out JFrame Window

Answer (score 1):

To alter the size of your image you can [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585894/1737819) or resize ([scale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244177/1737819)) your image. The sizes to which resize your image's can be get from the size of the frame.

If you have a frame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

you can get frame's size:

```
Dimension windowSize = frame.getContentPane().getSize();
System.out.println(windowSize);
```